# adding arrival process with peak hours in r

Tags: r

I am making a DES model with `simmer`. And instead of an exponential or equally distributed arrival process I would like an arrival process with two peak hours.
Right now I only have these two functions:

```
  add_generator("traffic" , trajectory = weekday , function() rnorm(100, 15, 5))%>% 
  add_generator("traffic2" , trajectory = weekday , function() rexp(100, 1/5))%>%
```

What I would like is a constant input of 10 cars/ hour and 50 cars at 8 - 10am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code generates `cph` cars per hour between `hstart` and `hstop`:

```r
library(simmer)
weekday <- trajectory() 

cph <- 10
hstart <- 8
hstop <- 10

simmer() %>%
  add_generator(paste0(cph,"carsperhour"), weekday , at(seq(from=hstart,to=hstop, by = 1/cph))) %>%
  run() %>%
  get_mon_arrivals()
#>               name start_time end_time activity_time finished replication
#> 1   10carsperhour0        8.0      8.0             0     TRUE           1
#> 2   10carsperhour1        8.1      8.1             0     TRUE           1
#> 3   10carsperhour2        8.2      8.2             0     TRUE           1
#> 4   10carsperhour3        8.3      8.3             0     TRUE           1
#> 5   10carsperhour4        8.4      8.4             0     TRUE           1
#> 6   10carsperhour5        8.5      8.5             0     TRUE           1
#> 7   10carsperhour6        8.6      8.6             0     TRUE           1
#> 8   10carsperhour7        8.7      8.7             0     TRUE           1
#> 9   10carsperhour8        8.8      8.8             0     TRUE           1
#> 10  10carsperhour9        8.9      8.9             0     TRUE           1
#> 11 10carsperhour10        9.0      9.0             0     TRUE           1
#> 12 10carsperhour11        9.1      9.1             0     TRUE           1
#> 13 10carsperhour12        9.2      9.2             0     TRUE           1
#> 14 10carsperhour13        9.3      9.3             0     TRUE           1
#> 15 10carsperhour14        9.4      9.4             0     TRUE           1
#> 16 10carsperhour15        9.5      9.5             0     TRUE           1
#> 17 10carsperhour16        9.6      9.6             0     TRUE           1
#> 18 10carsperhour17        9.7      9.7             0     TRUE           1
#> 19 10carsperhour18        9.8      9.8             0     TRUE           1
#> 20 10carsperhour19        9.9      9.9             0     TRUE           1
#> 21 10carsperhour20       10.0     10.0             0     TRUE           1
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! Do you know if it is also able to translate this to minutes instead of hours?

Comment: The time unit is up to you. If you want to simulate in minutes, just set `hstart` to `60*8`, `hstop` to `60*10` and cph to `10/60`, making `by = 6`